# My Website input field on Android causing keyboard to appear and disappear instantly

Tags: android, input, keyboard, event-listener

I am building a small site and ran into a small problem. I am using [MixItUp](https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/) to filter and sort blocks. I am also using a search field to search through the titles of each block and display relevant ones. Everything works fine on all devices and browsers except for Android.

On Android when I tap into the search field my keyboard slides up and then slides away again without giving me a chance to type anything. I tried googling the problem and only relevant thing I could find was [this post](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/45681/android-keyboard-flashes-up-and-disappears) but I am not sure how to proceed because I have no clue what event listeners would be disrupting the android one.

I am not a very experienced developer (self-taught and still learning lots) so I am not sure how I would go about correcting. My plan right now is to just remove pieces of code until keyboard starts working and then go from there once I identify what is causing it.

The Website is teste3.khalidsleiman.com

Answer (score 5):

I figured out it was a jQuery snippet that I was using to relocate the input field to a different spot on my page depending on window size. Now I only have it set to run that snippet on document load instead of window load and resize. Keyboard is showing up now.

Comment: Thanks for self answering that. Run into the same problem.